# How to increment date automatically daily in Excel sheet through python?

Tags: python, excel, date, increment

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("d.xlsx")
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

total_rows = sheet.nrows
total_cols = sheet.ncols

print(total_cols)
print(total_rows)

z = sheet.row_values(0,total_rows-1)
print(z)

if(z == datetime.now()):
    print ('EQUAL')
else:
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
    ws.write(0,total_rows-1,datetime.now())
```

I am not able to enter today's date.
Basically, in A1 I have written yesterday's date, and I want to check in row 0 exactly how many dates are there then compare them with today's date, if there is no available date of today, write it in the column which is at the last.

Comment: tried `=date(A1)+1` ?